# Links in IE have strange behavior

Tags: css

At the top of my web page I have some text links formatted by CSS.  In Chrome and Firefox they behave properly; in IE when each link is clicked the formatting changes and the text links get slightly larger; moving the links over to the right.  If you click a few links the last link gets bumped down to the next row.
Here is a link to the issue.
http://riverswest.com/dl/riverswest-site/index.html

Here is the CSS Code! The links start at: #topnav and end at: #bottom-nav-left
Thanks!

```
/* Color and Font Legend 

font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;

font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;

*/


/* Reset */

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;  
            background: transparent; font-size:10px; }

div, span, article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, a, ol, ul, li, 
table, tr, th, td, tbody, tfoot, thead {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}

img     { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }

table, tr, th, td, tbody, tfoot, thead {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

input, select, textarea, form, fieldset {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section      

{   display:block; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, blockquote, td, th, a, caption, em, strong, strike { 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:100%;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 100%; 
text-indent: 0;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
color: #000;
}

ol, ul, li  { list-style: none; }

img         { max-width:100%; }


/* Global */

html    {   }
body        { background-color:#000;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;  }



/* Headings */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }

h1 { font-size:24px; padding-bottom: 5px;  color:#FFF; font-style:italic;
        border-bottom:1px #FFF solid; margin:5px 0px 0px 15px;}
h2 { font-size:20px; }
h3 { font-size:16px; }
h4 { font-size:14px; }
h5 { font-size:14px; }
h6 { font-size:14px; }

h1 img, h2 img, h3 img, h4 img, h5 img, h6 img { margin: 0; }



/* Text Elements */

 p, li, a       { font-family:'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

 p              { color:#FFF; font-size:12px; line-height:150%; margin:15px 0; }
p .left     { margin: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 0; padding: 0; }
p .right        { margin: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1.5em; padding: 0; }

a               { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  } 
a:link          { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  }
a:visited       { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  }
a:active        { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  }
a:focus         { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  }
a:hover         { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;  }

 blockquote     { color:#000; font-size:12px; }

strong          { font-weight: bold; }
em           { font-style: italic; }

/* Images */


.image-frame    { padding:0px; border:1px #666 solid; margin:0px 0px 0px 48px; }


/* Lists */

ul li       { color:#000; font-size:12px; }
ol li        { color:#000; font-size:12px; }

li          {   }

ul.square   { list-style: square outside; }
ul.circle   { list-style: circle outside; }
ul.disc     { list-style: disc outside; }

ul          { list-style: none outside; }
ol          { list-style: decimal; }

dl              {   }
dt              {   }
dd              {   }



/* Tables */

table           { width:100%; }

tr          {   }
.odd            { background-color:#eee; }
.even       { background-color:#fff; }

th              { font-weight: bold; }
thead, th       { background: #ccc; }

tbody       {    }

th,td,caption   {   }
caption         {   }

tfoot           {   }
.tfooter        { background-color:#ccc; text-align:center; font-style:italic; }

caption         { background: #efefef; }



/* Miscellaneous */

sup, sub        { line-height: 0; }

abbr, acronym  { border-bottom: 1px dotted #666; }
address         {    }
del             { background:#FFCECE; color:#f00; }

code, pre       { background-color:#FF9; padding:2px 0px; margin:4px 25px;
                font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;                   
          font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; line-height:150%; }

/* Containers */

#outer              { width:960px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#000; }

#wrapper            { width:900px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#000; }

#logo               { margin:30px 0px 10px 0; float:left; }

#social-media       { float:right;  }
#social-media ul    { margin:30px 0px 0px 0px; }
#social-media ul li { float:right;  }
#social-media img   {   }

#topnav             { clear:both;  }
#topnav ul          { border-top:1px #FFF solid; border-bottom: 1px #FFF solid;
                    margin:10px 0; padding:10px 0 } 
#topnav ul li       { display:inline;   }
#topnav ul li a     { padding:0 15px; }

#topnav a:link      { color:#F60;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;} 
#topnav a:visited   { color:#F60;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#topnav a:active    { color:#9C0;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#topnav a:focus     { color:#9C0;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#topnav a:hover     { color:#9C0;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}


#banner             {  margin-bottom:30px; }
#slider             {  margin-bottomp:30px; }
/* LOWER NAVIGATION  */


#bottom-nav-left            {float:left; }
#bottom-nav-left ul         { margin:0px 0; padding:7px 0 } 
#bottom-nav-left ul li      { display:inline;   }
#bottom-nav-left ul li a        { padding:0 10px;   }

#bottom-nav-left a:link     { color:#9C0;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-left a:visited  { color:#9C0;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-left a:active   { color:#F60;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-left a:focus    { color:#F60;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-left a:hover    { color:#F60;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}


/* LOWER NAVIGATION SPLIT */


#bottom-nav-right           {float:right; }
#bottom-nav-right ul            { margin:0px 0; padding:7px 0 } 
#bottom-nav-right ul li     { display:inline;   }
#bottom-nav-right ul li a       { padding:0 10px;   }

#bottom-nav-right a:link    { color:#9C0;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-right a:visited { color:#9C0;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-right a:active  { color:#F60;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-right a:focus   { color:#F60;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#bottom-nav-right a:hover   { color:#F60;   font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}

#bottom-nav-border  { clear:both; border-bottom:1px #fff solid; margin:10px 0 0 0;}



#content-wrapper    {    }

#leftnav            {    }
#leftnav h2     {   }
#leftnav h3     {   }
#leftnav p      {   }
#leftnav img        {   }
#leftnav li     {   }
#leftnav a      {   }

#leftnav a:link     { color:#000;   }
#leftnav a:visited      { color:#000;   }
#leftnav a:active       { color:#000;   }
#leftnav a:hover        { color:#000;   }
#leftnav a:focus        { color:#000;   }

#leftside       {    }
#leftside h2        {   }
#leftside h3        {   }
#leftside p     {   }
#leftside img       {   }
#leftside li        {   }
#leftside a     {   }

#rightside      {    }
#rightside h2       {   }
#rightside h3       {   }
#rightside p        {   }
#rightside img      {   }
#rightside li       {   }
#rightside a        {   }

#rightside a:link       { color:#000;   }
#rightside a:visited    { color:#000;   }
#rightside a:active     { color:#000;   }
#rightside a:hover      { color:#000;   }
#rightside a:focus      { color:#000;   }




#content            { clear:both; width:900px;  }

#content h1         {   }
#content h2         {   }
#content h3         {   }
#content p          {  font-weight:normal;  }
#content img        {   }
#content li         {   }
#content a          {   }



#content a:link         { color:#000;   }
#content a:visited      { color:#000;   }
#content a:active       { color:#000;   }
#content a:hover        { color:#000;   }
#content a:focus        { color:#000;   }
#border-bottom          { border-bottom:1px #FFF solid; margin:0 15px 0   

15px;  }

#lower-content          { }
#lower-content img      { margin:20px 0px 0px 33px; border:1px #966 solid;}


 #gallery           {   }

#team           {   }

#faq                {   }

#events         {   }

#bottom-banner      {   }

#footer             { clear:both; margin-top:20px ; border-top:1px #FFF solid;    

padding-bottom:20px; }


#footer p           {   }

#footer a:link          { color:#000;   }
#footer a:visited       { color:#000;   }
#footer a:active        { color:#000;   }
#footer a:hover         { color:#000;   }
#footer a:focus         { color:#000;   }


#box1 {   }

#box2 {   }

#box3 {   }

#box4 {   }

#box5 {   }

#box6 {   }

#box7 {   }

#box8 {   }

#box9 {   }


/* Hide Print Headings */

#print-header       { display:none; }
#print-header h1    { display:none; }
#print-header h2    { display:none; }
#print-header h3    { display:none; }
#print-header p     { display:none; }

#print-footer       { display:none; }
#print-footer h4    { display:none; }

/* Hide Skip Links For Visually Impaired Screen Reader Users */

#skip   { display:none; }


/* Layout Extra */




/* Navigation Extra */



/* Forms */

#form1                  { margin:0 0 0 0;   }

ol li                   { display:block; padding:20px 0px 5px 0px;  

}

form ol                 { list-style-type:none; }

label                   { display: block; margin:10px 0 8px 0; 
                        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-      

serif; font-size:14px;
                        text-transform:uppercase;  } 

input, textarea, select         { display: block; width:400px;
                        pading:5px; }

input                   {   }

textarea                    { height:150px; }

select                  {   }

.submit                 { padding:5px 20px; width:140px; }


/* Miscellaneous  */
.center-text   { font-size:18px; font-style:italic; color:#9C0; text-align:center; }
.copyright-text { font-size:10px; font-style:italic; color:#333; }
.footer-text    { font-size:12px; font-style:normal; color:#FFF; text-align:center; 

}

.title          { font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#333;  }
.subtitle           { font-size:14px; font-style:italic; color:#333;  }

.artist         { font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#333;  }
.author         { font-size:14px font-weight:bold; color:#555;  }
.editor         { font-size:14px font-style:italic; color:#555;  }

.pub-date           { font-size:10px font-style:italic; color:#555; }
.article-date       { font-size:10px font-style:italic; color:#555;  }
.location           { font-size:10px font-style:italic; color:#555;  }

.address            { font-size:10px; font-style:normal; color:#000; }
.city           { font-size:10px; font-style:normal; color:#000; }
.telephone      { font-size:10px; font-style:normal; color:#000; }
.email          { font-size:10px; font-style:normal; color:#000; }
.website            { font-size:10px; font-style:normal; color:#000; }

.float-right        { float:right; }
.float-left     { float:left; }
.clear          { clear:both; }

.left           { text-align:left; }
.center         { text-align:center; }
.right          { text-align:right; }

.hide           { display:none; }
.block          { display:block; }
.inline         { display:inline; }
.inline-block       { display:inline-block; }
.inline-table       { display:inline-table; }

.first          { font-weight:bold; }
.last           { font-weight:bold; }
.left           { font-weight:bold; text-align:left; }
.right          { font-weight:bold; text-align:right; }

.added              { background:#D7D7FF; }
.removed            { background:#FFCECE; color:#f00; }
.changed            { background:#FFB; }

.red-bg         { background-color:#900; background-   

image:url(../images/bg/red.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
.yellow-bg      { background-color:#E6E600; background- 

image:url(../images/bg/yellow.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
.orange-bg      { background-color:#F96;    background-

image:url(../images/bg/orange.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
.green-bg           { background-color:#393; background-  

image:url(../images/bg/green.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
.blue-bg            { background-color:#36F; background-

image:url(../images/bg/blue.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }
.purple-bg      { background-color:#66F; background-

image:url(../images/bg/purple.fw.png); background-repeat:repeat-x; }

.red-txt        { color:#994D4D; }
.yellow-txt     { color:#FF0; }
.orange-txt     { color:#F90; }
.green-txt      { color:#0F0 }
.blue-txt       { color:#00A5F4; }
.purple-txt     { color:#93F; }



/* Success, info, notice and error/alert boxes - from Blueprint CSS Framework */

 .error, .alert, .notice, .success, .info {
padding: 0.8em; margin-bottom: 1em; border: 2px solid #ddd; }

.error, .alert { background: #fbe3e4; color: #8a1f11; border-color: #fbc2c4; }

.notice     { background: #fff6bf; color: #514721; border-color: #ffd324; }

.success    { background: #e6efc2; color: #264409; border-color: #c6d880; }

.info       { background: #d5edf8; color: #205791; border-color: #92cae4; }

.error a        { color: #8a1f11; }
.alert a        { color: #8a1f11; }

.notice a       { color: #514721; }
.success a      { color: #264409; }
.info a     { color: #205791; }
```

Comment: There's *way* too much CSS there; could you narrow it down to the relevant parts? I tried to do it myself, but I couldn't be sure I was getting the appropriate content.

Comment: Hello Andrew, I will clean up the CSS and send it to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your styles.css file:

```
#topnav a:visited {
    font-weight:bold
}
```

For some reason the default styling on the `a` with `font-weight:bold` didn't cascade in IE.  As a general tip you might want to use more classes instead of styling elements.  It ends up causing weird errors since the CSS is applied to your intended elements, but also unintended elements since the scope is so big.  I added `#topnav` to the new CSS so the scope would be limited to only the links in that section.

Comment: Hi Tedski,  Thanks for your reply.  I see what you are saying but I already have the #topnav a:visited {font-weight:bold} added to the CSS.  Should I add a class to the specific links?

Comment: I opened up your site today and I'm not seeing the problem anymore... did you figure out what it was?

Comment: Sadly, no!  At least not that I remember doing or that I am aware of.  I was waiting to hear back from you before I did anything, started editing images and when I went to view it in IE I noticed that the behavior was working.  It's possible I fixed something doing code clean up but nothing jumped out at me making me think I had found the problem.

Comment: I'm extremely new to coding websites and I find it very frustrating when I get things to work and I don't know why. :)  Thanks for your reply and follow up.  I will definitely be posting here again.

Comment: That's really weird that it happened in the first place, that kind of stuff is super frustrating.  Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.  It's a great community, I come here all the time.